# How to add custom text fields in Magento 2 admin module page

Tags: magento2, php, zend-framework

I have created a **new admin module page in magento 2** using this link http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/ext-best-practices/extension-coding/example-module-adminpage.html. Now I want to add two text boxes and a submit button in the same page. How can I do that?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can create text boxes on admin page by creating **form.php** in this path **yourvendor/modulename/block/form.php**

Create **_prepareForm()** function and in that function define the structure of text boxes which you want to create.

Firstly you need to create **fieldset** and using that fieldset you can **add new field**.

For example try below code :

```
protected function _prepareForm()
    {
        $model = $this->getModel();

        /** @var \Magento\Framework\Data\Form $form */
        $form = $this->_formFactory->create(
            ['data' => ['id' => 'edit_form', 'action' => $this->getData('action'), 'method' => 'post']]
        );

        $form->setHtmlIdPrefix('demofields_');

        $fieldset = $form->addFieldset(
            'base_fieldset',
            ['legend' => __('General Information'), 'class' => 'fieldset-wide']
        );

        $fieldset->addField(
            'title',
            'text',
            ['name' => 'title', 'label' => __('Your Title'), 'title' => __('Your Title'), 'required' => true]
        );

        $fieldset->addField(
            'description',
            'editor',
            [
                'name' => 'description',
                'label' => __('Description'),
                'title' => __('Description'),
                'style' => 'height:36em',
                'required' => true
            ]
        ); 
        $form->setValues($model->getData());
        $form->setUseContainer(true);
        $this->setForm($form);

        return parent::_prepareForm();
    }
```

After that load this **block** in your **layout file** where you want to show this fields.

run **cache:clean** command and check

Comment: How can I load this in to my helloworld.phtml

Comment: @VadivelMuruganM for that you need to  learn concept of model and controller better you can refer this link - https://www.ashsmith.io/magento2/